# Django - filter from db or compute in python

Tags: python, django, database

Suppose now I have 2 models, A and B.

And there is a many-to-many relationship between A and B

```
class B(models.Model):
    score_b = model.IntegerField()

class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ManyToMany(B, related_name='b_set')
    score_a = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)
```

==

The work flow is first I filter some A instance by `score_a`, and use them to query B with `score_b`

So a naive piece of code may look like this (Solution A)

```
## Solution A

stuff = {}

a_list = A.objects.filter(score_a__gte=100)
for a in a_list:
    qs = a.b_set.filter(score_b__gte=200)
    stuff[a.name] = [b.score for b in qs]

return stuff
```

But I'm trying my best to improve the performance

And the previous code seems to require `1 + len(a_list)` database access

So I would try to use `prefetch_related` (Solution B)

```
## Solution B

stuff = {}

a_list = A.objects.filter(score_a__gte=100).prefetch_related('b')
for a in a_list:
    qs = a.b_set.filter(score_b__gte=200)
    stuff[a.name] = [b.score for b in qs]

return stuff
```

However, it seems like the cached `b` will be ignore because `filter` is a different query. So the above code is not helping at all.

It now requires `1 + 1 + len(a_list)` database access because of the additional `prefetch_related` query

Now I come up with another idea which is filter b in python to reduce database access (Solution C)

```
## Solution C

stuff = {}

a_list = A.objects.filter(score_a__gte=100).prefetch_related('b')
for a in a_list:
    qs = a.b_set.all()
    temp = [b.score for b in qs if b.score >= 200]
    stuff[a.name] = temp
return stuff
```

And the number of database access should drop to `1` now, which is awesome

But I'm worried about doing the filter in python may be far more slower than filter in database

Will it runs faster in the Solution C than Solution A ?

Thanks!

### Edit

I edited the code snippet.

Sorry for my bad English and bad description that lead to misunderstanding.

My question is about whether I should always do the filter in database or It is ok to do it in python, especially when the latter can save some/many database access.

Comment: So you just want all `B` instances with a certain score restriction that are associated with at least one `A` with a score restriction of themselves. How do you want to treat duplicates?

Comment: thanks for your comment, I find out that I give a wrong example.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with a single db query through the ORM:

```
b_list = B.objects.filter(b_score__gte=200, a__score_a__gte=100).distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated my question, hope I have made it clear.

Comment: The answer is quite clear i think, in this example you can run in only one query, so there is no need to compute in python